# Separating the matched and unmatched values in mysql

Tags: mysql, match

I have two table with same fields. I want to compare one of the fields and move the matched and unmatched values in the 3rd and 4th table. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Assume table A and table B.

```
insert into table C values(select colA from A,B where colA=colB)
insert into table D values(select colA from A,B where colA!=colB)
```